# What's the pattern here?

Tags: word, pattern

From the lines below, can you determine what each is describing and the commonality between each answer? Once you get a couple, the pattern is obvious. Caveat: a handful of lines have a couple valid answers, and there may be some that I hadn't though of, but I am happy to accept any answer that seems viable (follows the pattern and fits the clue). Have fun:

> A very adaptable novel of manners
>   A simple mistake becomes a criminal offense
>   An officer's responsibilities
>   Trinkets
>   Scientific process, in many cases
>   A witch's incantation
>   Econ 101
>   Like most wanted men
>   Dun-Dun!!!
>   Repeatedly
>   The lunar cycle
>   "This pot's mine, boys!"
>   Fisher's methodology
>   "No use crying over spilled milk"
>   Orator's introduction
>   90's events inspire 10's satirical movie
>   "Time to get up!"
>   A real deluge
>   Quite the stark contrast
>   A children's game
>   "That's all there is to it"
>   Try different combinations
>   Ready to rollout
>   For hunting purists
>   A stunning tactic

For bonus points, can you come up with some good examples of the opposite of this pattern?

Comment: Is this what you had in mind for an opposite: no pain, no gain?

Comment: I meant linguistic freezes that use or instead of and e.g. 'hell or high water', 'fight or flight'

Comment: All or nothing, money or your life, sink or swim, death or glory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pattern is:

> any phrase in the form "_____ and _____"

Mostly complete list, but one or two left:

A very adaptable novel of manners

> Pride and Prejudice

A simple mistake becomes a criminal offense

> Crime and punishment

An officer's responsibilities

> Serve and protect

Trinkets

> Odds and ends (fm. GentlePurpleRain)

Scientific process, in many cases

> Trial and error

A witch's incantation

> Eye of newt and toe of frog
>  (Double, double,) toil and trouble (fm. Sabre)

Econ 101

> Supply and demand

Like most wanted men

> Armed and dangerous

Dun-Dun!!!

> Law & Order (fm. Mohair)

Repeatedly

> Over and over

The lunar cycle

> Waxing and waning (fm. psmears)

"This pot's mine, boys!"

> Read 'em and weep

Fisher's methodology

> Catch and release

"No use crying over spilled milk"

> Live and learn (fm. Curtis Reubens)

Orator's introduction

> Ladies and gentlemen

90's events inspire 10's satirical movie

> Pain & Gain (fm. Sabre)

"Time to get up!"

> Rise and shine

A real deluge

> (raining) cats and dogs

Quite the stark contrast

> Black and white

A children's game

> Chutes and Ladders

"That's all there is to it"

> Over and done with

Try different combinations

> Mix and match

Ready to rollout

> Locked and loaded (fm. Curtis Reubens)

For hunting purists

> Bow and arrow

A stunning tactic

> Shock and awe

Comment: I'm surprised just how many there are with multiple answers. Your answer for 'Dun-Dun' for example was quite different than what I had in mind

Comment: That answer is borderline in my mind, actually.

Comment: I suggest looking over your answers to lines 6, 9, and 16

Comment: Trinkets = "Odds and Ends"

Comment: "quite the stark contrast" could be chalk and cheese?

Comment: Dun-Dun!!! = "Law & Order," the TV show.

Comment: Witch's incantation = "(Double Double) Toil and Trouble?"

Comment: And I guess the satirical movie is probably [Pain & Gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_%26_Gain)

Comment: Not sure "day and night" is especially related to "lunar cycle" - perhaps "waxing and waning"?

Comment: @lorimer Mohair is right, that annoying noise is practically the only reason I don't watch Law & Order.

Answer (score 3):

Filling in some of lorimer's gaps:

"No use crying over spilled milk"

> Live and learn.

Ready to rollout

> Locked and loaded